# Redundancy with optional variables in swift - is there an elegant solution?

Tags: swift

This might be seen as a minor issue, but it just looks ugly in the code and I would like to solve it.

I have an optional variable declared and would like to change it later, if it is not empty (`!= nil`) The code for this is:

First declare

```
private var myVariable: Int? // Optional Integer variable
```

Later decrement, when not empty

```
{
    if myVariable != nil {myVariable!--} // Same condition in "if" and in unwrapping
}
```

I need the `!` even when it is assured with the `if-condition` that the variable has a value. This is redundant and means that Swift must do the same comparison twice.

Is there a more elegant way in doing this?

My current Xcode Version is 6.3.

Comment: `myVariable = myVariable.map {$0 - 1}` although I'm not sure this is actually much better.

Comment: How about this? `myVariable? += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question is [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

```
myVariable?--
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as examples, you could do the following:

```
myVariable?++
myVariable?--
myVariable? += 10
```

This uses optional chaining - if `myVariable` has non-nil a value, it is unwrapped and incremented. Otherwise the statement returns nil.

Comment: Or just `myVariable?++`

Answer (score 0):

```
if let myVariable = myVariable { //if - let unwrapping
    myVariable-- //don't need the suffix now
}
```

Comment: This is actually one of the things I've tried and that did not work. First you define the `myVariable` with `let` which defines it as read-only. No way to decrement it or assign a value to it. Second - even if you would be able to change the value of `myVariable` inside the if-body - it would still only change the value of the inner `myVariable` not the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the point of giving "!" after variable is so the Swift doesn't need to double check. You said with "!" that the myVariable is not nil and it has a value so it won't double check.

Comment: You do need to check the value is not nil before using the force unwrap operator. If you use it and the optional is nil your program will crash.